# How to create Vue3+composition API app on demand

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have couple of Vue2 applications that I plan on rewriting into Vue3+composition API. The problem though is that they are not initialized immediatelly, but after some user interaction.

In Vue2, I could:

```
import MyApp from './MyVue2App.vue';
import Vue from 'vue';

export default { Vue: Vue, MyApp: MyApp }
```

and then I could get these exports via `requirejs`, so applications could have been rendered solely on demand.

I was unable to do something similar with Vue3 though. The ugliest possible solution would be storing both the `createApp` and `MyApp.vue` in `window` (I'd really like to avoid using global variables), e.g.:

```
// main.ts
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './MyVue3App.vue;

// export default { createApp, App } <- doesn't work, can't import from the bundle
window.MyVue3App = App
window.createApp = createApp
```

```
// index.html
<script src="vendor.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

<div id="foo"></div>

<button onclick="window.createApp(window.MyVue3App).mount('#foo')">
  Mount APP
</button>
```

Does anyone know how to make this working without using global variables? I am on a clean `vue-cli` project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by building the application as a library.

```
// vite.config.ts

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'path/to/build.ts',
      name: 'ComponentsLib',
      fileName: format => `components-lib.${format}.js`
    }
  }
})
```